# user authentication in wso2 via curl

Tags: authentication, curl, wso2

I need to authenticate admin user via curl command so I can pragmatically add,delete, modify users in wso2

I can call the api end points for user add/mod/delete no problem. But without being able to first authenticate to wso2 it is all for naught. When I send the curl command I get no response back, and nothing shows in the logs.

This is my basic curl command, right out of the books:
curl -X POST "https://xxxxxxx.com:9443/login/portal" -H "Content-Type: application/x-form-urlencoded" -d "username=uid&password=foo&grantType=password"

Comment: 1. Which WSO2 product are you referring to? 2. Is your requirement to add/edit/delete users programmatically?

Comment: wso2 identity server v5.3.0. Yes I need to manage users via api calls, programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SCIM APIs with basic authentication to manage users.

If you want to use OAuth2 tokens, you can get them like this.

```
curl -k -d "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>" 
    -u <Consumer_key>:<Consumer_secret> 
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
    https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token
```

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/SCIM+1.1+APIs

Comment: OK many thanks, I can create a test user with scim, but running into an issue with adding roles. The only reference in the docs is to Groups, but when I try to use the endpoint Groups I get a 404 groups not found in the user store